# Several threads writing the same data on a buffer: are there consistent arguments stating that it is dangerous?

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, race-condition

Imagine a situation in which several threads can write on a certain buffer (no restrictions on its size) and all of these constraints apply:

1. Before all the threads start, the buffer is initialized to zero.
2. A thread may write on the buffer or not.
3. If a thread writes on the buffer, it writes a certain string of bytes (let's call it `V`, with `V` being not only made of zeros and being the same for all threads).
4. No thread ever read from the buffer.
5. The fact that a thread writes on the buffer, and what it writes on the buffer, does not depend on the fact that other threads have written on the buffer, or not.
6. If a thread starts writing on the buffer, then it writes it completely.
7. The threads write on the buffer without following a precise order of the bytes.

Question is: after all the threads have stopped (and this happens only provided that they have finished writing on the buffer, if they started to), am I guaranteed, under any real-world or at least plausible architecture, that:

1. either the buffer contains all zeros,
2. or the buffer contains exactly `V`?

If not, is there any consistent argument stating that another string of bytes, call it `V'`, may be written? If so, what could be the differences between `V` and `V'`? Why?

Comment: The question is not so much "does the buffer contain either 0s or V": it does contain whatever you have written - the more interesting question is: "if I read the buffer, am I guaranteed to read either 0s or V". The answer to the latter depends on the memory model of your *real-world or at least plausible architecture*, which in turn depends on the language/execution framework/cpu you are using...

Comment: Is V the same for all threads?

Comment: @assylias : please, would you post a detailed answer? I would like to read your point of view, which is different from the ones of the people that already answered - provided your interpretation of the question is the same.

Comment: @gd1 I am not certain enough of the answer to post one - but my feeling is that if your buffer is large enough (and split across cache lines), its update to/from main memory will not be atomic and a reading thread might read a partial update from main memory if visibility is not enforced with an appropriate memory barrier. Now the window over which this partial update will be observable is probably very short on most architectures.

Comment: @gd1 Where the language comes into play is: if you read the buffer from a Java program for example, and you read a partial update, and you don't use any synchronization, then the JVM might hoist the value and your thread could keep using that partial value for ever as it won't re-read the shared variable.

Comment: If you write this in C++, the compiler can and will mess it all up, if not today, then in some future version.   It's allowed to rewrite your code any way it pleases as long as the result is the same as the code you wrote, and in doing so, it's allowed to assume you have no races-- so since you *do* have races, all bets are off.  For example, it can rewrite your thread callback with code that first writes V to the buffer but shifted a byte upward, then shifts the contents of the buffer downward.  When two threads do that at the same time, result can be other than V or 0's.

Comment: @DonHatch : really the compiler can do that? Imagine there is a single thread but I receive a signal, in the signal handler cannot I rely on the fact that the buffer is either going to be filled with zeros or some portion of V (maybe partial, but not messed up)? Of course I wouldn't dare do that in a signal handler, but I think you get the point. Thanks for clarifying, and feel free to post an answer I can upvote.

Comment: @gd1 I was avoiding posting an answer because that would require properly gathering references :-)  But for example see these for eye-opening writeups of the crazy things the C++ compiler can and does do:  https://blog.mozilla.org/nnethercote/2015/02/24/fix-your-damned-data-races/  and https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong

Answer (score 1):

Number 6 appears to be the clincher, it basically states that a write to the buffer is atomic and non-interruptible. Hence the contents will either be 0 or a consistent `v`.

Of course, that's not the normal case with threads unless you use something like a mutex.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is guaranteed (if all threads really write the same values to the same locations). Stores of bytes are atomic. This means that no values can be "made up" by the system. The only possible values for each byte in the buffer are either zero (because it was pre-initialized) or the value that all threads write.

The question now is: can a zero slip though somehow? Can a location in the `byte[]` somehow end up appearing to not ever have been written to? Answer: no. It is unclear which write comes through but they are all the same. If at least one thread wrote to the buffer, it will contain exactly `V`. (If no one ever wrote it will be all zeros. This is trivial. So I'm assuming that at least one thread wrote to the buffer).

Of course your reading thread must wait for the writers to terminate in order to force a memory barrier. The barrier guarantees that all previous writes are visible to the reader.